# blank space in strings from java/webservice(json) yields different byte arrays

Tags: java, json, string, byte

I am currently writing some acceptance tests to a jersey 2-0 webservice (json) before refactoring some methods in the project, and i have stumbled upon a problem with asserting blank-space strings from the webservice.

I get the following output from my webservice:

```
"Boxes": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": " ", //Yes this is a white-space
        "genre": "genre",
        "info": "some info",
        "rating": "3",
        "artist": "Artist 1"
    }
],
```

And i convert my response to JSONObject from the webservice as following:

```
public static JSONObject responseToJsonObject(HttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
    return new JSONObject(responseString);
}
```

Then in my test, is do normal asserts like so:

```
//* http request creation omitted *//
JSONObject jsonResponse = JsonTranslator.responseToJsonObject(httpRequest)
JSONArray boxes = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("boxes ");
JSONObject result = boxes .getJSONObject(0);

assertEquals(" ", result.getString("title"));
```

Problem is that this last assert fails.

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected : 
Actual   :
```

And i probably know why, the byte arrays yield two different results. One has a byte of `[32]` (the one created in java) and the one from the webservice has `[-62,-96]`

I have never encountered this problem before. And if i try to convert without the `"UTF-8"` in the `EntityUtils` method i get an even worse result (`Â`  byte array: `[-61,-126,-62,-96]`

I can see my webservice's `content-type` header is properly set as `application/json`

Can anyone explain what happens here?

Comment: There are plenty of blank space characters that aren't space (32). Are you sure the sending side isn't doing something funny?

Comment: The same assertEquals() do fine with: assertEquals("Artist 1", result.getString("artist")); //this includes white spaces aswell. Im currently trying to fetch the data directly from the DB so i can follow the data directly from the root, and hopefully locate where the problem comes from at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character you are getting there is not a "normal" space. It's a no-break space. The same character that in HTML would be described with `&nbsp;`.

Its unicode value is `'\u00A0'`. Its UTF-8 representation is `C2 A0`, which is what you are getting in your byte array.

I believe if you tried the following assert it would work:

```
assertEquals("\u00A0", result.getString("title"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this is exactly whats happening. The new assert worked like a charm.